# Start NSArray from position 1 not 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageview that displays three photos you can swipe through. I am wanting the scrollview to start at position 1, so that it starts in the middle of my three photos and you are able to swipe left and right. However I am having issues. Here is my current code:

```
    -(void)setScrollViewForImage
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrImages.count; i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrImages.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrImages.frame.size;
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imgView.image = [arrImages objectAtIndex:i];
        self.scrImages.tag = 1;
        [self.scrImages addSubview:imgView];
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code it may be useful to you,

```
-(void)setScrollViewForImage
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrImages.count; i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrImages.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrImages.frame.size;
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imgView.image = [arrImages objectAtIndex:i];
        self.scrImages.tag = 1;
        [self.scrImages addSubview:imgView];
        self.scrImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrImages.frame.size.width * i,self.scrImages.frame.size.height);
        self.scrimages.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.scrimages.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
    }
}
```

in this code the scrollview's pagination is enabled and it will be set to images at index 1. it will also provide functionality for swipe left and right.